# RxJava: why subscribing to shared observable changes emitted items

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I stumbled on some puzzling behavior I can't explain. I distilled the example below from a much bigger rx chain, so do not be surprised why on earth I would do this. I just want some insight on why this is happening! :)

```
enum class Request {
    Request1,
    Request2
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val requestStream = PublishSubject.create<Request>()

    val stateChanges = requestStream.share()

    stateChanges
        .delaySubscription(requestStream)
        .subscribe({ println("received $it") })

    // Comment this and it changes the output!
    stateChanges.subscribe()

    requestStream.onNext(Request.Request1)
    requestStream.onNext(Request.Request2)
}
```

So. if you run the program above, it will print:

```
received Request1
received Request2
```

But if you comment `stateChanges.subscribe()`, suddenly `Request1` gets lost and it prints only this:

```
received Request2
```

Can you explain it? 
Also I would like to know if it is possible to have the above setup to emit both items even in absense of extra `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal case, `share` is already connected to `requestStream` and due to `delaySubscription(requestStream)`, `share` gets it's second `Observer` before `requestStream` sends it the Request1. So `requestStream` has two `Observer`s and sending Request1 to the first adds another `Observer` to the second consumer, the `share`, therefore, the end subscriber there gets Request1.

In the commented out case, `share` hasn't connected to `requestStream` yet, therefore `requestStream` can only notify the `delaySubscription`. `delaySubscription` triggers `share` which then subscribes to `requestStream`. However, `PublishSubject` emits items only to the current snapshot of `Observer`s and can't see its first `onNext` added a new `Observer` in the meantime. Thus, Request1 doesn't reach the `println`.

This corner case in not handled by `PublishSubject` as it would require its `onNext` to remember which `Observer` has already received the current item and keep retrying in case the set of current `Observer` changed. This add memory and time overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll need some quiet time to process it.